# How to write formula that references specified number of cells relative to the formula' location in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example: `Sum 7 cells directly to the left of the formula.`

Notably, the formula should work when inserting new column to the left of it or somewhere inside the range. Not extending the range, not skipping newly inserted column.

Comment: `OFFSET()` function may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is by defining a relative named range. Start by selecting cell H1. Then, on the ribbon, go to the **Formulas Tab > Defined Names Group** and click **Define Name**. In the **Name:** field, type *RangeToLeft*, then in the **Refers to:** field, type `=!A1:G1` and click Ok (note the omission of the sheet name, as well as the $ signs).

The name “RangeToLeft” can now be used in any worksheet formula from column H through to column XFD, and will always refer to the seven cells immediately to the left of the formula, no matter how many columns are inserted or deleted. For example, in cell H1 you can use the following formula:

```
=SUM(RangeToLeft)
```

The only time this will fail is if it’s used in columns A to G, as there are less than seven cells to the left remaining. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I had previously come up with this formula but the accepted answer is so simple and elegant that I'm not sure if it's worth posting any more. Still, for the record a regular formula not using offset might be:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:H1,COLUMN()-6-COLUMN(A1)):INDEX(A1:H1,COLUMN()-COLUMN(A1)))
```

[image]

With insertion to left:

[image]

With insertion in range:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"the formula should work when inserting new column", but how it should work?

```
[H1]=SUM(A1:G1)
```

The default behavior is to keep both references with dedicated cell. It means if `A1:G1` will be extended inside it, e. g. new column before `B`, it will be changed to `A1:H1`.

You can anchor any end with the length:

```
=SUM(A1:OFFSET(A1;;6)) fixed left end
or
=SUM(OFFSET(G1;;-6):G1) fixed rigth end
```

Or you can fix the range related to the current cell:

```
[H1]=SUM(OFFSET(H1;;-7):OFFSET(H1;;-1))
```

Replace `;` by `,` following your regional settings.